# Add every two consecutive lines in a column and divide it with the former and Print

Tags: text-processing

I have a input file of almost 2000 lines. I have to do a calculation and print it in the third column.

Example of what I have to do with the Input File:

```
n ID1_1 n/(n+k)
k ID1_2
```

**Input File:**

```
 10 ID1_1
 20 ID1_2
  1 ID3_1
  9 ID3_2
 20 ID20_1
 15 ID2_1
300 ID2_2
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 10 ID1_1 0.33
 20 ID1_2 
200 ID3_1 0.11
  9 ID3_2
 20 ID20_1 /*I would just leave it like that*/
 15 ID2_1 0.047
300 ID2_2
```

Do you have any easy way to solve it?
Thanking you.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. When asking for help here, you need to show us the work you have done. First so that we don't suggest things you've already tried and second so we know you've put some effort into it and are not simply expecting us to do your work for you.

Comment: 200/(200+9)=0.11? I think there's a typo in your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import re
import sys
fil = sys.argv[1]
with open(fil) as f:
    m = re.split(r'[\n\r]+(?= *\d+\s+ID\d+_1)', f.read())
    l = []
    for i in m:
        l.append(re.sub(r'(?s)^(\s*(\d+)\s+([^_]+)_1)([\n\r]+\s*(\d+)\s+\3_2)$', \
             lambda m: m.group(1) + " "+ str(float(m.group(2))/(float(m.group(2))+float(m.group(5)))) +  m.group(4),i))
    print('\n'.join(l), end = "")
```

Save the above script as `script.py` and then run it by,

```
python3 script.py inputfile
```

**Example:**

```
$ python3 f.py file
 10 ID1_1 0.3333333333333333
 20 ID1_2
  1 ID3_1 0.1
  9 ID3_2
 20 ID20_1
 15 ID2_1 0.047619047619047616
300 ID2_2
```

Answer (score 3):

Given the input you show, the following should work:

```
<infile sed -e '$!N;2i\' -e '3k 
s|\(\(.*  *\).*_1\)\n\(\(.*  *\).*_2\)$|[\1 ]P\2d\4+/p[\3]pc|;t
s|^[ _ID0-9]*|[&]pc|;P;D' | dc
```

For me it prints...

```
 10 ID1_1 .333
 20 ID1_2
  1 ID3_1 .100
  9 ID3_2
 20 ID20_1
 15 ID2_1 .047
300 ID2_2
```

...because I set `dc`'s precision to 3, but with a precision of 10...

```
 10 ID1_1 .3333333333
 20 ID1_2
  1 ID3_1 .1000000000
  9 ID3_2
 20 ID20_1
 15 ID2_1 .0476190476
300 ID2_2
```

Besides the output precision, it also differs from your *expected output* in the third row - but I think that is more due to a typo in the question?

Anyway, to understand it you have to consider that I must first parse the output into two forms for `dc` - `dc` will `P`rint a `[string]` without a following `\n`ewline, or it will `p`rint a number or a `[string]` with one. Besides also possibly e`x`ecuting a string as a `dc` macro, it can do little else with them. But, with numbers, it is very capable.

So with `sed` I first append the `$!N`ext line to the current one if the current line is `!` the `$`last. On the second line I `i`nsert the string `3k` to stdout - which is a `dc` command for setting the precision to 3.

Then I attempt a substitution:

```
s|\(\(.*  *\).*_1\)\n\(\(.*  *\).*_2\)$|[\1 ]P\2d\4+/p[\3]pc|
```

This will only be successful if pattern space currently contains at least one space followed at some point by `_1` followed immediately by a `\n`ewline character followed at some point by at least one space followed at some point by `_2` followed immediately by the `$`end of pattern space.

This means that the above substitution only affects line pairs like...

```
...ID_1
...ID_2
```

...and not any others. When it does affect them it transforms their contents into workable `dc` script. It next `t`ests if the substitution was successful, and if so, it branches out of the script, thereby printing the results of the substitution and executing no more `sed` commands. `dc` takes `sed`'s standard output as standard input, so, for example, after `sed` alters the first two lines to look like this:

```
[ 10 ID_1 ]P10d20+/p[ 20 ID_2]pc
```

...`dc` then handles that input in the following way:

- `[ 10 ID_1 ]` - push the string between the square brackets onto the top of the stack *(which pushes everything already on the stack down by one)*
- `P` - `P`rint the top of stack without a trailing `\n`ewline and pop it off *(which pulls all values on the stack below it up by one)*
- `10` - push the number 10 onto the top of the stack
- `d` - `d`uplicate the top of stack
- `20` - push the number 20 onto the top of stack
- `+` - add the top of stack and the 2cd from top of stack *(while popping both)* and push the result onto the top of stack
- `/` - divide the 2cd from top of stack *(now our `d`uplicated `10`)* by the top of stack *(our `10 20 +` result)* *(while popping both)* and push the result onto the top of stack
- `p` - `p`rint the top of stack *(without popping it)* followed by a trailing `\n`ewline.
- `[ 20 ID_2]` - push the string onto the top of stack
- `p` - `p`rint the top of stack *(again, without popping it)* followed by a trailing `\n`ewline
- `c` - `c`lear the stack

And so `dc` prints:

```
 10 ID1_1 .333
 20 ID1_2
```

But if `sed` does not successfully match and change pattern space as already described, then it is left with other lines to handle. In that case `sed` sandwiches the first sequence of `[ ID_0-9]*` it can between `[` and `]` while also appending the `pc` commands. It then `P`rints pattern space up to the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space then `D`eletes same before starting over with what remains. And so `sed` works on a one-line lookahead throughout, printing working `dc` script at `dc` all the time.

This means the whole file is processed in-stream - as `dc` and `sed` both provide output while they process. In this way - provided your input is similar to the example in the question - you could easily process 2million lines in the same fashion, or else handle a log file in real time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am finding this code very difficult to understand. Can you please explain me s|\(\(.*  *\).*_1\)\n\(\(.*  *\).*_2\)$|[\1 ]P\2d\4+/p[\3]pc|;t
s|^[ _ID0-9]*|[&]pc|;P;D' part?

Comment: @Srilakshmi - done.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input is in a file called `a.txt`:

```
paste a.txt <(awk 'NR%2?ORS=FS:ORS=RS' a.txt | awk '{print $1/($1+$3)}' | sed G)
```

The first `awk` will bring the successive pair of lines in a single line. The next `awk` will do the desired calculation. The `sed` will insert a new line in the result and redirect the output to `paste` which will bring it and input together.

It will give the following:

```
10 ID1_1    0.333333
20 ID1_2
1 ID3_1     0.1
9 ID3_2
15 ID2_1    0.047619
300 ID2_2
```

Comment: There's no need for a tmp file, you can do it directly: `paste file <(awk 'NR%2?ORS=FS:ORS=RS' file | awk '{print $1/($1+$3)}' | sed G)`

Comment: Hello Ketan, Your script perfectly works with the given data. But I have one problem in my dataset, Sometimes I have an unpaired element like :  ID20_1 (I have updated in my question just now), in that case it is calculating it wrong.

Comment: @Srilakshmi with the new update to the problem, I think you can either use `grep` to filter out the single records or insert ghost records for single ones if they are not too many.

Comment: @Ketan Actually I dont know how many are Single. But I am writing a script that would only print in pairs for the input file.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the whole thing with a single `awk` command:

```
$ awk '{if(NR%2){n=$1;last=$0;}else{print last,n/(n+$1)"\n"$0}}' file
10 ID1_1 0.333333
 20 ID1_2
  1 ID3_1 0.1
  9 ID3_2
 15 ID2_1 0.047619
300 ID2_2
```

The idea is to simply check whether the current line is even numbered and i) if it is, we print the previous line (`last`) along with the desired calculation and ii) if it isn't we save the current line as `last` and the 1st field as `n`.

You can control the number of decimal place printed by using `printf`:

```
$ awk '{if(NR%2){n=$1;last=$0;}else{printf "%s %.2f\n%s\n",last,n/(n+$1),$0}}' file
10 ID1_1 0.33
 20 ID1_2
  1 ID3_1 0.10
  9 ID3_2
 15 ID2_1 0.05
300 ID2_2
```

Here's the same basic thing in Perl:

```
$ perl -lane 'if($.%2){$n=$F[0];$last=$_;}
              else{printf "%s %.2f\n%s\n",$last,$n/($n+$F[0]),$_}' file
10 ID1_1 0.33
 20 ID1_2
  1 ID3_1 0.10
  9 ID3_2
 15 ID2_1 0.05
300 ID2_2
```

Comment: Hello terdon, I have a bit of complication in my dataset that I just realised. Sometimes there are also lines which are not in a pair and are just single. So with this code all, the moment a single element arrise (ie the one without the pair) it is calculating all the rest wrongly.

Comment: @Srilakshmi well, that's why you need to think about your question before asking it and try some things out. We can't know what you need. Edit your question with a fuller example and show us what you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: Actually I have such a big dataset that I did not notice the problem before. I am analysing the genome but for this I could not figure out how to do it. So I simplified it and trying to learn how to do this kind of calculation through programming.

Comment: @Srilakshmi I understand, I have often had the same problem. However, you must understand that I just spent 10 minutes helping you and now you tell me that there are more complications. You're the one who needs to do the work, not us. We will help but don't expect us to do everything. So, take the time to research your question and only ask when you have all the necessary data. That way we can help you without wasting your time or ours.

Comment: I did the research and I could not find a similar one like this. So I thought maybe someone can help me and I learn from there.

Comment: @Srilakshmi my point is that we deal with specific problems here. Not "write me a script that does X". Among other things, we want to feel that the asker has _tried_ before asking and does not simply expect us to do the work. The easiest way to demonstrate that is to include the things you tried in your question.

Comment: I get your point. Next time I will also put what I have tried and where i am stuck. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After OP editing (see added term):

```
awk '
/ID.*_1/{
    n=$1
    idx=$2
    sub("_1","_2",idx)
    printf s"%s",$0
    s="\n"}
$2==idx{
    printf " %.2f\n%s",n/(n+$1),$0}
END{
    print""}' file
```